# Azure Functions in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am trying to run my Python code with Azure Functions using Visual Studio Code. I have run the "Hello World" project with Azure Functions in VS Code, but I am looking for a way to deploy my Python code with Azure Functions. I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me with this issue by introducing a relevant tutorial or sharing some ideas.

Comment: Have a look of this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#publish

Comment: If you are using VS code, you can also use VS code to deploy.

Comment: Any more doubts?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a function app on azure. This is a container to deploy your function.

Then you have two ways to deploy:

1, use VS code:

[image]

click the upload button, and then select the folder you want to deploy, the subscription, and select the function app you created just now.

2, use cmd:

Go to the root folder of your function, and run this command:

```
func azure functionapp publish <FunctionAppName>
```

The name of function app is absolutely unique, so if you have the authority then your folder will deploy to this function app directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well the thing is that I am trying to run the Azure Functions in VS Code locally to test it before deploying the function. However it seems there is a syntax error because I get "400 Bad Request" error! I want to read a timeseries data from a JSON file, process the data (using pandas module) and then apply some mathematical operations. But it seems that the code which is running well in Spyder or other IDEs, cannot run properly with Azure Functions. I would appreciate it if you could help me run the Python code locally with Azure Functions in VS Code.

Comment: @NJE Yes, I have notice your another question just now.

Comment: My main question is how I can transfer the code from Python to Azure Functions and run it in VS Code...is there a way to simply copy/paste the code lines from Python script and convert them to Azure Functions? Or in other words, what would be the appropriate Azure Function for each command in Python.

Comment: @NJE Paste code is basiclly no problem. I am trying to solve, If I have some update I will let you know.:)

Comment: @ Bowman Zhu I really appreciate your kind help. Yes I also think there should not be a problem if the whole code or most parts are pasted from the Python script, but I have no idea why this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is [Azure for Python Developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/)

and you want to deploy python code to azure, there are three options for you to choose with regard to different code situation:

1. [Deploy a web app with VS Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-deploy-app-service-on-linux-01)
2. [Deploy Docker containers to Azure App Service with Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-deploy-containers-01)
3. [Create and deploy serverless Azure Functions in Python with Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-vs-code-serverless-python-01)